# How to get the number in a html element for a specific class attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, count

With Javascript, I want to find the element that contains the "swiper-active-switch" attribute among all the possible  elements and have it return to me in which span element it is contained.

```
<span class="swiper-pagination-switch"></span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-switch"></span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-switch"></span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-switch"></span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-switch swiper-visible-switch swiper-active-switch"></span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-switch"></span>`
```

Here's how I get the count of span, but I'm not sure how to iterate through them, find my desired attribute and then find out which line it occupies in the source code. In the above example, it is the line 5. So I'd want to get the value "5" back, for example.

try:

```
var counter = $(this).find("span").length; //full number
alert(counter);
var total = 0;
var hhh = $(this).html();
alert(hhh);
$("span").each(function(){
    var n = parseInt($(this).text());
if(n > 0){ //check if element is greater than 0
    total ++;
}
});
total = total + 2;
var index = $(".swiper-pagination-switch").index()+2;
alert("total:"+total+" current:"+index);
//and now the actual number for an active page.
```

Comment: Do you actually need to know what line of the source code it's on or do you just need to know that it's the 5th span? Just because the two happen to be the same in your very small example doesn't mean that's always the case, or that line in the source code is indicative of an elements position in the DOM.

Comment: I only want to know that it's the 5th span.

Comment: Is there a parent element that contains those spans? Are there other elements in the same parent before them?

Comment: parent element is <div class="pagination">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('span.swiper-pagination-switch').index($('.swiper-visible-switch'))
```

will give you the result, which is 4 because it is 0-indexed, if you want 5, just plus 1.

**[Add the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/3asBr/)**

Comment: I got the result "-1".

Comment: @searchforit Demo added, check it.

Answer (score 1):

If the loop is necessary to achieve your activity,and it's more similar to your code, you should try this :

```
var total = $('span').length;
var searchClass="swiper-pagination-switch";
var searchIndex;

//there is an index return by jQuery.each method
$('span').each(function(index){
    if($(this).hasClass(searchClass)){
        searchIndex = index;
    }
});
console.log('total:'+total+' active:'+searchIndex);
```

Comment: "total" and "searchIndex" are undefiened.

Comment: for the undefined total, i did a typing mistake "lenght" -> "length".
for the undefined searchIndex, maybe, the class doesn't exist in your code when the each function is fired.
add a "console.log($(this).attr('class'));" in the loop to make sure.

Comment: ok it works. but the result for "total" = 9 and for "active" = 8.

Comment: $('span') detects span in the page you should do something more specific like $('.pagination span') instead